# How do I catch ClientResponseErrors returned by the Cloud SQL API?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I'm connecting to Cloud SQL postgres via the python connector like this:

```
ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC

def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
    conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
        "myinstance",
        "pg8000",
        user="myuser",
        db="mydb",
        enable_iam_auth=True,
        ip_type=ip_type,
    )
    return conn

pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
)

try:
    with pool.connect() as connection:
        result = connection.execute(query).fetchall()
        for row in result:
            result_value = row[0]

# This doesn't work
except ClientResponseError as ex:
    if ex.code == "429":
        backoff_seconds = 30
        logger.warning("Getting 'Too Many Requests' error from Cloud Sql api. Waiting to reconnect.")
        sleep(backoff_seconds)
    else:
        raise
```

Sometimes I see these errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/instance.py",
> line 414, in _refresh_task refresh_data = await refresh_task File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/instance.py",
> line 350, in _perform_refresh metadata, ephemeral_cert = await
> asyncio.gather( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/refresh_utils.py",
> line 98, in _get_metadata resp = await client_session.get(url,
> headers=headers, raise_for_status=True) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 643,
> in _request resp.raise_for_status() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py",
> line 1005, in raise_for_status raise ClientResponseError(
> aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 429, message='Too Many
> Requests',
> url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/myproject/instances/myinstance/connectSettings')

It spews those errors occasionally, but recovers. I want to handle this more elegantly, but it seems trying to catch `ClientResponseError` is not working. How can I catch these errors and set a backoff timer?

Maybe I need to catch the call to `connector.connect()`?

Comment: Any updates on this one ?